# Эмуляция hdmi монитора

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, драйвер, hdmi

Есть пк с видеокартой nvidia, к пк должны подключаться через parsec и прочее, для использования 3d приложений, проблема в том, что без подключенного монитора или hdmi заглушки изображение выводится только в 800х600 и изменить это нельзя, даже окна настроек windows некорректно работают без монитора.
Однако при подключении через rdp windows в систему на время сеанса добавляется новый видеоадаптер и разрешение можно менять, однако рендер идет через видеокарту только частично.

В общем, необходимо эмулировать hdmi подключение к видеокарте, чтобы был доступен вывод изображения и звука.

В какую сторону копать чтобы решить данную проблему? Может есть простые примеры готовых драйверов под это задачу или есть уже готовое решение?

Comment: ¿Где хоть какие-то подробности для воспроизведения этой проблемы? ¿Какой пк, какая видеокарта, какая версия windows, что сообщает dxdiag?

Comment: Решением в данном случае и является HDMI - заглушка. Есть еще костыльное решение через linux и wine, если хотите с бубеном попрыгать, и ваше ПО работает в wine.

Comment: @user7860670, какие еще подробности тут могут быть? Любой пк с дискретной картой на вин 10 без подключенного монитора или заглушки стартануть, то там будет то что я описал, к чему этот комментарий вообще?

Comment: @gbg 100% есть решения через драйвер видеоадаптера, для этого и задан данный вопрос, но по-видимому тут никого с полезным опытом и не осталось, поэтому придется своими силами справляться.

Comment: @Kopkan - если найдете, будет интересно об этом почитать.